# Using onTap to navigate to a specific page

Tags: dart, flutter

I receive this error whenever I try to navigate by clicking on an icon in a drawer

error message when I click on the drawer's item
[image]

```
...onTap:_profile
//jump to function...
Widget build (BuildContext context){
void _profile() {
  Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "/Profile");}...
```

this is how the main function looks like

```
    void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new LoginPage(),

  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/Feed": (BuildContext context) => new first.Feed(),
    "/Settings":(BuildContext context) => new sixth.Settings(),
    "/Profile": (BuildContext context) => new fifth.Profile(),
    "/Search": (BuildContext context) => new second.Search(),
    //"/Signout":(BuildContext context) => new LogoutPage(),
    "/Notify": (BuildContext context) => new third.Notifications(),
    "/Feedback": (BuildContext context) => new fourth.Feedback(),
    "/Tabs": (BuildContext context) => new Tabs(),.....
```

Update:

I am using google sigin with firebase authentication, but I need to redirect the user after signing in to view my application.

I am new to flutter so I still do not know how to work around this so here what I did

```
Future<String> _testSignInWithGoogle() async{
//implement signin
runApp(
  new MaterialApp(
    home: new Tabs(),
  )
);
 return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

It is confusing, but I do not understand how else can I redirect the user after signing in to view Tabs(), the current flow of my program is:
loginPage()->onPressed: _signIn -> calls _testSignInWithGoogle()-> creates new Tabs().

Comment: Can you include the call to new MaterialApp so we can see how your routes are set up?

Comment: @CollinJackson I have added the main function to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me, so please post a reduced test case if you can. Are you sure there aren't any other `Navigator` or `MaterialApp` instances in your code?

Here is the code I am using to test with.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _profile() {
      Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "/Profile");
    }
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Login'),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: _profile,
          child: new Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('You made it!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new LoginPage(),

  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>
  {
  "/Profile": (BuildContext context) => new Profile(),
  }
  ));
}
```

If you can't figure out what's different between your version and mine, you could try implementing `onGenerateRoute` instead of passing the `routes` argument to `MaterialApp`.

Comment: I think you pointed out the problem, yes I do have another MaterialApp() instance beside the one included in the main function. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I figured out that I missed setting up my routes in the MaterialApp() in _testSignInWithGoogle() method ! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: and may I ask you if you find my structure logically correct ?

@CollinJackson

Comment: What you're doing is fine, I generally try to avoid calling `runApp` more than once because multiple `MaterialApp`s make the program harder to reason about though. Consider `popAndPushNamed` as a way of getting back to the login page.

Comment: Will try this, thanks again for you helpful feedback.